# Django ORM query deferring field that it shouldn't

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have two different queries on nearly identical models and mysql tables, but for some reason one of them works fine and the other always chooses to defer a DateTime field, causing it to do thousands of additional queries later when trying to access that data. In my view the two calls are:

```
sent_messages = list(SentMessage.objects.by_tags_and_profile(tags, profiles, start_date, end_date))
received_messages = list(ReceivedMessage.objects.by_tags_and_sources(tags, sources, start_date, end_date))
```

The first works fine, but the second comes back as a list of `ReceivedMessage_Deferred_date`

The associated models are:

```
class ReceivedMessage(models.Model):
    _db = "received_message"
    msg_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_column="created_date")
    tag = models.IntegerField()
    source = models.IntegerField()

    objects = ReceivedMessageManager

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'received_message'
        ordering = ['-date']
        unique_together = ('source', 'msg_id', 'tag')

class ReceivedMessageManager
    def by_tags_and_sources(self, tags, sources, since=None, before=None):
        sql = """SELECT *
                 FROM received_message rm
                 WHERE rm.tag IN (%s) AND rm.source IN (%S)
              """
        params = [tags, sources]
        if since:
            sql += ' AND rm.created_date > %s '
            params.append(since)
        if before:
            sql += ' AND rm.created_date < %s '
            params.append(before)

        return self.raw(*safe_sql(sql, *params))
```

The SentMessage and SentMessageManager classes are nearly identical, except replace "source" with "profile" and in the model change

```
date = models.DateTimeField(db_column="created_date")
```

to

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I suspect that ReceivedMessage deferring the date/created_date field has something to do with the model variable name not matching the database field name like it does for SentMessage, but even if that's the case I'm not sure how to make it work (this is part of a massive system and changing those names to match would be a huge undertaking with risks that we want to avoid).

Additional Note: I am aware that with a query this basic I could easily just use `ReceivedMessage.objects.filter(...)` and in fact that DOES solve the problem, but we made a conscious decision to keep the query logic in that manager class so that if any fields or indices ever change we wouldn't have to go searching for everywhere in the code base that we queried that way to change it.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I did try changing the query from SELECT * to listing out each individual field, including created_date, in case the explicit call for that field would force it to not defer but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your `select FIELD_NAMES...` query when you have the `select created_date` did you by chance put a `select created_date AS date` not sure if that's valid SQL, but you get the idea.

I think when the ORM is loading the results of a raw query back to the python object, it expects the fields selected to line up exactly with the model names. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields has some details on that.